# Eclipse Oxygen PHP Project - Including path from vendor is not recursive

Tags: php, eclipse

I finally took eclipse as IDE for contributing to a PHP side project. However, As I started to set up the IDE Environment I noticed that the include paths are not recursive.

i.e. that means if I have lookup in folder `vendor/kohana` and `vendor/kohana/classes`, I must specify both of them in the include path and not only `vendor/kohana`. Eclipse also pops a message that **Exclusion filters are applied to sub-directories**.

Now I already solved that by altering manually the eclipse project core pref file with the endless list of include paths (little dirty work), but I can hardly imagine that's a proper solution. Also It doesn't cover future problems with including new packages in project.

Is there a better way to address this problem? Did I miss anything in IDE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to the specific `vendor` directory, and assuming you're using `composer`, did you check if you had a "Configure > Add composer support" on the project by right-clicking on it? It should then properly include the various vendor directories to your build path.

Comment: The Composer updated the build path. I don't know what happened in the first time, but when now I "updated" the build path, it inserted the right include paths. The plugin also prevents me from removing them manually from the Eclipse UI.

Thanks